# how to check dns resolve error by libcurl when dns hijacking?

Tags: dns, libcurl

i use libcurl to check the dns of url is normal or not in my game client,

in normal condition，i can get "`CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)`" error in libcrul

but if "**DNS hijacking**",i will get another error url from IAP。。

so,libcrul will get error url content and retrun "`curl_res==OK`"

it's badly,and not my result.

so ,i try to get reponse url to vertify DNS hijacking,

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlStr);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);               
curl_easy_getinfo(curl,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL,&response_url);
```

Unfortunately,`CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` is same as my requeset url ,i don't kown why ?

so ,can you give me some ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

See, from libcurl's perspective that's not a failure (if the subsequent transfer itself actually succeeds too). It resolves a name and does a transfer and that works just fine.

You then need to be creative and figure out a way to detect if you're being "tricked" by a hijacker, like for example getting a page from a host name you *know* shouldn't exist.